# Are there any differences to C# between North America, Asia, Europe?

Tags: c#, .net, region

I just took online (non-course related) test on C# and this question came up to me:

Are there any difference to the C# language based on country/region?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the `DateTime` typesetting will be different depending on the culture. For instance in the U.S., it will read, the same goes with currencies, dialogs (the `YesNo` buttons will be different, etc.):

```
10/15/2014 8:16:08 PM
```

Whereas in France it will read:

```
15/10/2014 20:17:08
```

**Example** (with the `csharp` interactive shell):

```
Mono C# Shell, type "help;" for help

Enter statements below.
csharp> using System.Threading;
csharp> using System.Globalization;
csharp> Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now); 
10/15/2014 8:18:12 PM
csharp> Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
csharp> Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);                                
15/10/2014 20:18:46
```

In short all settings that depend on a country/culture/natural language will be set locally (as @joppiesaus mentions, Europeans use a comma where Americans use the "decimal dot"). But the compiler is uniform.

Note however this has nothing to do with `C#` itself. After all `C#` is a standardized language with a deterministic virtual machine. But the "environment" in which it runs, can set default values differently.

Finally, as @philippelhardy indicates, there are some patents that can cause problems. For instance *Mono* is a clone of *C#*. While *Microsoft Silverlight* can play *DRM* protected media files, *Mono's Moonlight* can't, because Microsoft didn't license their *PlayReader*. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moonlight_%28runtime%29#DRM) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

No, there are no differences whatsoever. There is just one language specification. Period.

Imagine what happens to a programming language specification that changes depending on the region you are in...

What if this has a different meaning in the USA then in Europe:

```
decimal d = 1.500;
```

Is it 1.5 (one and a half) or 1,500 (one thousand five hundred)?

Comment: does that really deserve a down vote? I assumed this was the case and I googled it, I figured the best place to ask was here.

Comment: What about `DateTime`, currency,... formatting...

Comment: @CommuSoft unrelated to the language

Comment: @CommuSoft: That is about the language specification, not the use of it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: I agree. But one still should be careful. Some people assume `double.Parse("1.5");` will work, regardless of the environment, while in many European countries this will fail. I agree that's not part of the language. But is something one should take into account.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: another part (initiated by @philippelhardy) is some patented content like playing DRM protected content: Silverlight can while Moonlight can't. Again it's not part of the "actual question", but closely related.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no. It's a programming language and I don't see why it would be different in other countries.

The long answer is no, but there are some differences(not in the programming language itself, thought).
For example: I live in the Netherlands, so the computer sees me like I'm Dutch. If I enter `Convert.ToDouble(someString)`, in the US the `.` would seperate the number, while in Europe the `,` seperates the number.

That's related to the culture the program is running in(`CultureInfo`), which is partly based on region(pre-installed computers, internet, ...)

Comment: Your account is set to use Dutch culture, which is then seen in `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`. It's not inferred from your location (hopefully).